# Who is the strongest human in the DC Universe?

Tags: dc, super-hero

I'm curious to know who the strongest Human is in the DC universe, I'm not interested in including any aliens or other species.

Comment: How do you define strongest? Why is this of interest to you? Why only human? Are you interested in the comics only? The animated series? The films universe? Earlier films?

Comment: @edlothiad "Why is this of interest to you? Why only human?" - I don't think they have to answer these questions of they don't want to. On-topic questions don't have to be justified like that.

Comment: @RogueJedi, no one _has_ to act on any suggestions anyone gives them. Hence why they’re called suggestions. I was merely giving the OP tips based on the fact we’ve had questions in the past of a similar style be heavily downvoted for being vague. Questions that only have a title sometimes are. May have also helped keep the question open.

Comment: because most of the well known heroes are non human

Comment: @Edlothiad why is the asker's motivation of interest to you?

Comment: @ConradBennishJr The Asker’s motivstion is of interest to the site. Considering Stack Exchange is a platform to answer questions to problems you’ve had, having a problem is really the core of asking a question, since our site is a bit niche, instead of having a problem, it’s recommended to provide the interest or motivation for the question as to why this question might be interesting, as opposed to just a random whimsical thought one was too lazy to research.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Almost certainly the flash (though it does depend how you count it obviously). Flash (with the exception of his link to the speed force ) is for the most part entirely human and yet due to the connection to the speed force is capable of trading blows with all the justice leagues top hitters. it does however depend on weather you view that as "real strength" or not. As for which flash the debate of which flash is faster/stronger is big and always changing and I do not want to get into it right now.

other possibility's include the spectre who i dismissed as being a host for a powerful organism rather than powerful in his own right; plastic man who i dismissed as not really being human and probably bane(though that's extremely debatable) if we're being really stringent on what constitutes a human.

I also assumed you were talking about raw power and not strength in a vaguer meaning "the ability get what you want done." in which case it might well fall to a politician, a businessman or one of the DC universes array of magicians.